# Vuejs2 axios mutation: update an object

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following user.js file that "works" but need to improve it:

```
import * as mutationTypes from "../mutation-types";
import user from "./user_data";

export const state = user;

export const getters = {
  user: (state) => state
};

export const mutations = {
  [mutationTypes.SET_USER]: (state, payload) => {
    state.username = payload.username;
    state.avatar=payload.avatar;
    state.locale=payload.locale;
    state.currency=payload.currency;
    state.userid=payload.userid;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  setUser: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit(mutationTypes.SET_USER, payload);
  }
};
```

via axios I receive this payload that represent the full user, thus the state:

```
payload:{
    userid: "EA7FD2025132E3254A11FE70E9746A52",
    username: "boss",
    level:  6,
    active: true,
    company:'mySite ltd',
    landingpage:'dashboard',
    locale:'es',
    currency:'eur',
    subscriptionlevel:'',
    subscriptionexpiry:'',
    credits:0,
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john.doe@mysite.com",
    avatar: "/static/avatar/john.jpg",
    job: "mySite - FOUNDER & CEO",
  }
```

how can I fully update the state without updating the single subparameters
ie something like this:

```
export const mutations = {
  [mutationTypes.SET_USER]: (state, payload) => {
    state = payload;
  }
};
```

I tried with

```
state = Object.assign({}, payload)
```

but it does not work :-(

here the vuex state:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state and related functionality (mutations, getters,...) in Vuex is conceived to contain several pieces of information, several slices, that you can use to manage your application state.

It is an unusual use case to mutate the whole state at once: I answer myself if it is even possible.

For the reasons explained by @Dan in his/her answer, when you point a Javascript object to a new one in the `mutation` method, the original object is not changed, but instead the reference passed to the method points to `payload` in your example. As a consequence, the original object is not changed. Dan Abramov wrote a great article about mutation - among others - in his [Just Javascript](https://justjavascript.com) blog posts: please, I recommend you to review them if you have time.

So, instead of trying to mutate the entire `state`, it is better to mutate just a slice, say `state.user`.

For it to work properly, you need to initialize the Vuex `state` as follows (assume that `user` is imported from the external file):

```js
export const state = {
  user: user
}
```

Or more concisely, using [ES6 object property values shorthand syntax](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals):

```js
export const state = {
  user
}
```

You can define as many properties here as you need to reflect your actual application state and fill them with initial values.

And then, you can safely mutate this slice on the corresponding `mutation`:

```js
export const mutations = {
  [mutationTypes.SET_USER]: (state, payload) => {
    state.user = payload;
  }
};
```

You need to modify the related `getters` as well:

```js
export const getters = {
  user: (state) => state.user
};
```

Comment: I am sorry @Joe. The problem probably has to do with the way Vue maintain the state, in the context also explained by Dan in his/her answer. Please, can you try the suggested new approach?

Comment: Hi!
This solution seems working.

actually `user` is a "sub" state since it is in separate .js file
I would like, at least to understand how it works,  to change it to `state.user`
but all my attempts so far failed :-(

Comment: Just added screenshot of vuex status

Comment: And @Joe, it does not work if you try `state.user = payload`?

Comment: no, `state.user = payload` has been my first attempt, but it added the object `user` to the state
well, actually this is what @Dan suggested me to do.. but I do not know how to create the `state.user` at beginning :-(

Comment: let's try with this question:

How shall I modify the .js to achieve that `user` is an element of `state`?
thanks

Comment: Please, see my update. You only need to return an object with keys the different state slices the application requires. I hope it helps.

Comment: Please, see my new update, when I use the imported `user` variable. I hope it helps.

Comment: yes I've seen, thanks.. I'm testing.. it basically works but I want to understand how to apply to other situation, thus ... if I really understood :-)

Comment: It is ok @Joe. Please, let me know if you need any further help or you have any doubt, I will be glad to help you if I can.

Comment: hi!
sorry for late answer but I've tried to apply in different ways and Understood a little better how to manage.
now I have new questions.. but will open a new request
thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: Hi @Joe. You are welcome. Please, do not need to apologize. Thank you very much for marking the answer as correct. I will try to follow your new question.

Comment: :-)
just fyi the question is the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855065) 
regards

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much Joe. I am happy to know that you were able to find a solution for the new problem as well. Great job @Dan.

Answer (score 0):

**Why that didn't work**

Whenever you reassign a variable that already contains an object, it doesn't change the existing object, only points the variable to a new one.  The old reference connection is lost.  So reassigning `state` in the mutation does nothing to the actual underlying `state` object.  It makes no difference if you use `=`, `Object.assign`, or the `...` spread operator.

It's best to put the user object on state like `state.user`:

```
state = payload  // ❌ Only reassigns the variable reference, no changes to original
```

```
state.user = payload  // ✅ Changing a reference property via the parent reference
```

Another way to look at it is to remember that `state` in the function is not always necessarily the same as `state` in the module, in fact it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it.

Some reasons not to use the `state` object directly:

1. Harder to change it in the mutation.
2. Harder to use with `mapState` helper
3. Code Readability / Testability

---

### `store.replaceState`

If you still want to use `state` that way, and you're not using Vuex modules, this can sometimes be done very easily using [`store.replaceState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#replacestate).  It can be done with modules too, but it's a little trickier:

```js
export const mutations = {
  [mutationTypes.SET_USER]: (state, payload) => {
    this.replaceState(payload);
  }
};
```

Comment: hmm.. this because object is not primitive data type, therefore it is referenced only?
well, not it works, but will try to modify the structure according to your suggestions
Thanks

Comment: still not working: returns
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceState' of undefined`
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how you've set up your store for `this` to be undefined, but that's ok because `replaceState` is a little trickier when using Vuex modules anyway.  But as I said, I recommend not using `state` directly like that.  Answering your first question:  It would be the same for a primitive.  Any variable reassignment does nothing to whatever the variable *used* to point to.