# Vue.js pass $store data from different modules

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router

Hi I need to understand how to "pass" some $store values from `settings` module to `header` module, being the `$store` updated by `settings`module

I have this app.vue module:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view name="sidebar" />
    <router-view name="header" :handleSettingsDrawer="handleSettingsDrawer" />
    <v-main class="vue-content">
      <v-fade-transition>
        <router-view name="settings" />
      </v-fade-transition>
    </v-main>
    <router-view name="footer" />
    <app-settings-drawer
      :handleDrawer="handleSettingsDrawer"
      :drawer="settingsDrawer"
    />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

in the `<router-view name="header" />` there are a couple of `v-menu` to select currency and language:

```
<v-menu offset-y close-on-click>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn v-on="on" small fab class="mr-3">
      <v-avatar size="30">
        <v-img :src="currentLocaleImg"></v-img>
      </v-avatar>
    </v-btn>
  </template>

  <v-list dense class="langSel">
    <v-list-item
      v-for="(item, index) in langs"
      :key="index"
      @click="handleInternationalization(item.value,item.rtl)"
    >
      <v-list-item-avatar tile class="with-radius" size="25">
        <v-img :src="item.img"></v-img>
      </v-list-item-avatar>
      <v-list-item-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

in the `script` section I import the `availableLanguages` and `availableCurrencies` , I set them in `data()` where I also reference the `user`:

```
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { icon: "settings", text: "Settings",link: "/settings" },
        { icon: "account_balance_wallet", text: "Account", link:"/tos" },
        { divider: true },
        { icon: "login", text: "Log In",link:"/auth/login" },
        { icon: "desktop_access_disabled", text: "Lock Screen",link:"/auth/lockscreen" },
        { icon: "exit_to_app", text: "Logout",link:"/auth/logout" },
      ],
      langs: availableLocale,
      currs: availableCurrency,
      user: this.$store.state.userdata.user,
    };
  },
```

then, in `computed:` I have the 2 functions that should get the current value of `curr` and `lang`:

```
currentLocaleImg() 
{
    return this.langs.find((item) => item.value === this.$store.state.userdata.user.locale).img;
  },
  currentCurrencyImg() {
    return this.currs.find((itemc) => itemc.value === this.$store.state.userdata.user.currency).img;
  }
}
```

BUT the value of `this.$store.state.userdata.user` is updated firing the `loadData()` function mounted in the `<router-view name="settings" />` module of `App.vue`

```
mounted(){
    this.loadData();
},
methods:
{
async loadData(){
  let jwt=sessionStorage.getItem('jwt');
  try{
      const res = await this.$http.post('/ajax/read_settings.php', {"jwt":jwt});
      this.$store.dispatch("setUser", res.data.user); 
      this.$store.dispatch("setLocale", res.data.user.locale);
      this.$store.dispatch("setCurrency", res.data.user.currency);

  }
```

the problem is that `header` module does not have the value of `this.$store.state.userdata.user.locale`
(and `.currency`) and I get twice the following message:

```
    vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined
```

I do not know how to "pass" the data from one module to the other (or perhaps because the `header` is rendered before the `settings` module) and therefore the value of the currency and of the language are not known yet

What's wrong in this procedure?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a race condition in which you try to use data in the template that isn't loaded yet.  But first, avoid setting store data directly into component data because the component data won't be updated when the store changes.  Replace this:

```js
user: this.$store.state.userdata.user
```

With a computed:

```
computed: {
  user() {
    return this.$store.state.userdata.user;
  }
}
```

You can use `v-if` to conditionally render only when some data is available:

```html
<v-img :src="currentLocaleImg" v-if="user"></v-img>
```

The `currentLocaleImg` computed will not even trigger until `user` has some data so you will avoid the error.  Do the same for `currentCurrencyImg` if necessary.